# Android Kotlin openid AppAuth registerForActivityResult not being called

Tags: openid, appauth, registerforactivityresult

Using openid AppAuth for login, registerForActivityResult is not called after the successful login, it stops on the login page itself.
Expecting : After successful login the web page should close and redirect to calling Activity.
Below is sample code :

```
private lateinit var authorizationService: AuthorizationService
lateinit var config: AuthorizationServiceConfiguration
```

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.myLayout)

    authorizationService = AuthorizationService(this)

    binding.btnLogin.setOnClickListener { getAuth() }
}
```

```
private fun getAuth() {

    config = AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
        Uri.parse("{{Domain in URL}}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
            Uri.parse("{{Domain in URL}}/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1_SUSI_Test")
    )

    var params: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
    params["p"] = "B2C_1_SUSI_Test"

    val request = AuthorizationRequest
        .Builder(config, CLIENT_ID, ResponseTypeValues.CODE, Uri.parse(URL_AUTH_REDIRECT))
        .setScopes(
            "openid", "profile", "email",
                "{{Domain in URL}}/api/app.user.basic" 
        )
        .setRedirectUri(Uri.parse(URL_AUTH_REDIRECT))
        .setAdditionalParameters(params)
        .build()

    val intent = authorizationService.getAuthorizationRequestIntent(request)
    launcher.launch(intent)
}
```

```
private val launcher =
    registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->

        Log.d("TAG", "registerForActivityResult = $result")

        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val ex = AuthorizationException.fromIntent(result.data!!)
            val result = AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(result.data!!)

            if (ex != null) {
                Log.e("TAG", "registerForActivityResult : Error $ex")
            } else {
                // val secret = ClientSecretBasic(GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET)
                val token = result?.createTokenExchangeRequest()
                Log.d("TAG", "Token : $token")
            }
        }
    }
```

Android manifest file as below

```
<activity
            android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="replace">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="{{app package}}" />
                <data
                    android:host="{{domain}}"
                    android:path="/oauth2redirect"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is what worked for me for AppAuth `v0.11.1`.

- In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file: remove the `<application android:noHistory="true" />` option if it's there, or just set it to `false`.
- In the same file add the following intent filter to the Activity that has the login button:

```xml
<intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.example.yourproject.HANDLE_AUTHORIZATION_RESPONSE"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And that is it. This much configuration was enough to get it working.

Here is my authentication code in the content of a GitHub user authenticaion:

```
    private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()){
        if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val ex = AuthorizationException.fromIntent(it.data!!)
            val result = AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(it.data!!)

            if (ex != null){
                Log.e("Github Auth", "launcher: $ex")
            } else {
                val secret = ClientSecretBasic(GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET)
                val tokenRequest = result?.createTokenExchangeRequest()

                service.performTokenRequest(tokenRequest!!, secret) {res, exception ->
                    if (exception != null){
                        Log.e("Github Auth", "launcher: ${exception.error}" )
                    } else {
                        val token = res?.accessToken
                        viewModel.setToken(token!!)
                        // Move to Github screen
                        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun githubAuth() {
        val redirectUri = Uri.parse("com.example.yourproject://oauth2redirect")
        val authorizeUri = Uri.parse("https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize")
        val tokenUri = Uri.parse("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token")

        val config = AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(authorizeUri, tokenUri)
        val request = AuthorizationRequest
            .Builder(config, GITHUB_CLIENT_ID, ResponseTypeValues.CODE, redirectUri)
            .setScopes("user repo admin")
            .build()

        val intent = service.getAuthorizationRequestIntent(request)
        launcher.launch(intent)
    }
```

This article was good help: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/authenticating-on-android-with-the-appauth-library-7bea226555d5